# Tuning the update statement in SQL Server or upgrade the query in T-SQL like Oracle plsql (for idx update)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my update query in SQL Server, it is taking a long time to execute. I need help to re-write the query.

```
UPDATE d
SET d.CA_PAID_TO_DATE = s.canextpdate
FROM 
    (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(POLNUM)) POLNUM, CA_PAID_TO_DATE 
     FROM [DataAnalytics].[dbo].[tbla_hst_policy_history]  
     WHERE transmonth = '202112'
       AND CA_PAID_TO_DATE IS NULL) AS d
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         LTRIM(RTRIM(CAPOLNUM)) CAPOLNUM, 
         CASE 
             WHEN LEFT(canextpdate, 2) > 85 
                 THEN '19' + canextpdate 
                 ELSE '20' + canextpdate 
         END canextpdate  
     FROM [DataAnalytics].[dbo].[tblh_lldca] 
     WHERE transmonth = '202112' ) AS s ON (d.POLNUM = s.CAPOLNUM);
```

Comment: Your `RTRIM`/`LTRIM` functions on the columns you `JOIN` are going to make your query completely non-SARGable; that is your problem. Why do you have data in 2 different tables that might or might not have leading spaces? *Note that trailing spaces are ignored for comparison (`'abc' `, `'abc '` and `'abc     '` are all seen as equal), so the `RTRIM` does nothing other than to cause non-SARGability.*

Comment: Start by posting DDL for your tables, some sample data, and the execution plan. I can see room for major improvements beyond trimming - and the code itself suggests schema issues. Nor does it help to post some oracle code that is COMPLETELY unrelated.

Comment: If you really do need to [`trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the columns being joined you could add _persisted computed columns_ to the tables and index them.

Answer (score 1):

Your rtrim() and ltrim() is completely questionable. You would be killing the use of indexes that way.
That one put aside, your statement is unnecessarily complex than what it needs to be. You could write it simpler and should be faster even in the existence of those ltrim(rtrim)()):

```
UPDATE d
SET CA_PAID_TO_DATE = CASE 
             WHEN LEFT(canextpdate, 2) > 85 
                 THEN '19' + canextpdate 
                 ELSE '20' + canextpdate 
         END
FROM 
      SELECT canextpdate      
      FROM [DataAnalytics].[dbo].[tblh_lldca] d 
      WHERE transmonth = '202112' and 
          exists (
              SELECT * FROM [DataAnalytics].[dbo].[tbla_hst_policy_history] h  
              WHERE h.transmonth = '202112'
                AND h.CA_PAID_TO_DATE IS NULL 
                AND LTRIM(RTRIM(h.CAPOLNUM)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(d.POLNUM))
              );
```

Instead of ltrim(rtrim()), use a varchar\nvarchar field and fill with trimmed values once (and create index on that field).